# SQL Sub Queries

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT id, subject, date
FROM mail
WHERE date > some_date
```

I need to cross reference the id returned by the above query with another table to get the user's username. How can I do it in one query?

Right now I am doing this:

```
foreach (id in result)
{
  query = String.Format("SELECT username from USERS where id = {0}", id);
}
```

Expected column output:

```
id   subject   date   username
--------------------------------
```

Comment: To clarify, you want run a single query to get the `MAIL.id`, `MAIL.subject`, `MAIL.date`, and `USERS.username`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT m.id, 
       m.subject,
       m.date,
       u.username
  FROM MAIL m
  JOIN USERS u ON u.id = m.id
              AND u.id = {0}
 WHERE m.date > some_date
```

Comment: Why is the "AND u.id = {0}" part of the JOIN and not the WHERE?

Comment: @James Curran: Because of using an INNER join, placement doesn't matter.  If it were an OUTER join, the `USERS.id` filtration would occur before the JOIN and potentially affect the resultset.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT m.id, u.username, m.subject, m.date 
FROM mail m
inner join USERS u on m.id = u.id 
WHERE m.date > @some_date
```

Of course, if you want it in C#/LINQ:

```
 var msgs =  from m in db.Mail
     where m.date > some_date
     select new
     {
         m.id,
         m.subject, 
         m.date, 
         m.Users.Username
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM mail WHERE date > some_date
)
```

Comment: The OP clarified, wants columns from both tables.